# Streaming struct array into ordering system

Tags: c++

The overall purpose of this program is to set up a food ordering service for a restaurant. The program is meant to pull food items and prices from a .txt file, display them and let the customer pick items, then print the bill on the screen. I've gotten everything here to work, except the printCheck function.

It seems like the program ends before that function runs. My code is below.

//Module 9 Project

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

struct menuItemType
{
    string menuItem;
    double menuPrice;
};

    menuItemType menuList[3];

    void getData(menuItemType menuList[3]);

    void showMenu(menuItemType menuList[3]);

    void printCheck(double);



int main(){

    getData(menuList);
    showMenu(menuList);
    printCheck;

return 0;
}

void getData(menuItemType menuList[3]) //This pulls the items and prices from the text file into the array
{
    //declare variables
    ifstream in_stream;
    int i;

    //open txt file
    in_stream.open("menuitems.txt");

    // loop to pull items from txt file into struct array
    for (i = 0; i < 3 ; i++){
        in_stream  >> menuList[i].menuItem >> menuList[i].menuPrice;
    }

}

void showMenu(menuItemType menuList[3])//shows the user the menu items and tells them how to select them
{
    int selection;
    double total;
    int sentinel = 9;


    //Welcome message and instructions for how to order
    cout << "Welcome To The Restaurant" << endl;
    cout << "Please select the items you would like: " << endl;
    cout << "Press 9 to complete your order." << endl;

    //displaying items from array onto screen
    cout << menuList[0].menuItem << " $" <<  menuList[0].menuPrice << endl;
    cout << menuList[1].menuItem << " $" <<  menuList[1].menuPrice << endl;
    cout << menuList[2].menuItem << " $" <<  menuList[2].menuPrice << endl;


    //while loop to allow user to select as many items as needed, and calculate total
    while (selection != sentinel){
        cin >> selection;

            if (selection == 1){
                total += 2.45;
                cout << "You've selected Bacon" << endl;
            }

            else if (selection == 2){
                total += .99;
                cout << "You've selected a Muffin" << endl;
            }

            else if (selection == 3) {
                total += .50;
                cout << "You've selected coffee" << endl;
                }
        }
}

void printCheck(double total)
{
    double after_tax;
    const double tax = .05;


    cout << "Total Bill: $" << total << endl;

    after_tax = total + (total * tax);

    cout << setprecision(2) << "Total Check After Tax: $" << after_tax << endl;


}
```

Comment: `printCheck;` does nothing. You have to use `()` operator to call functions like `printCheck(3.14);`

Comment: You need to intialize `total` to `0` and return the total amount from `showMenu` function. Make `showMenu` to return `double`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

struct menuItemType
{
    string menuItem;
    double menuPrice;
};

    menuItemType menuList[3];

    void getData(menuItemType menuList[3]);

    void showMenu(menuItemType menuList[3]);

    void printCheck(double);



int main(){

    getData(menuList);
    double total = showMenu(menuList);
    printCheck(total);

    return 0;
}

void getData(menuItemType menuList[3]) //This pulls the items and prices from the text file into the array
{
    //declare variables
    ifstream in_stream;
    int i;

    //open txt file
    in_stream.open("menuitems.txt");

    // loop to pull items from txt file into struct array
    for (i = 0; i < 3 ; i++){
        in_stream  >> menuList[i].menuItem >> menuList[i].menuPrice;
    }

}

double showMenu(menuItemType menuList[3])//shows the user the menu items and tells them how to select them
{
    int selection;
    double total = 0.0;
    int sentinel = 9;


    //Welcome message and instructions for how to order
    cout << "Welcome To The Restaurant" << endl;
    cout << "Please select the items you would like: " << endl;
    cout << "Press 9 to complete your order." << endl;

    //displaying items from array onto screen
    cout << menuList[0].menuItem << " $" <<  menuList[0].menuPrice << endl;
    cout << menuList[1].menuItem << " $" <<  menuList[1].menuPrice << endl;
    cout << menuList[2].menuItem << " $" <<  menuList[2].menuPrice << endl;


    //while loop to allow user to select as many items as needed, and calculate total
    do {
        cin >> selection;

            if (selection == 1){
                total += 2.45;
                cout << "You've selected Bacon" << endl;
            }

            else if (selection == 2){
                total += .99;
                cout << "You've selected a Muffin" << endl;
            }

            else if (selection == 3) {
                total += .50;
                cout << "You've selected coffee" << endl;
                }
        } while (selection != sentinel)

        return total;
}

void printCheck(double total)
{
    double after_tax;
    const double tax = .05;


    cout << "Total Bill: $" << total << endl;

    after_tax = total + (total * tax);

    cout << setprecision(2) << "Total Check After Tax: $" << after_tax << endl;


}
```